# How can I get white rectangles around these charts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Need a rectangular border block around these charts to make them look like elements in a dashboards and charts enclosed within these rectangles.

All in eclipse.
html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3> Students with Activity in Course (Bar Chart)</h3>
        <div class="bor">
      <canvas id="scooby" width="400" height="100"></canvas>    
</div>
    <h3> Students with Activity in Course (Line Chart) </h3>
    <div>
        <canvas id="freddy" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <h3> Students with Activity in Course</h3>  
    <div>
        <canvas id="velma" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bor {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: we can't guess at your markup. please provide, and show what you've tried

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what kinds of questions you can ask here. For instance, this question lacks code and a description of what you've tried so far. What have you tried?

Comment: @Joy, to clarify a bit further your question, please, edit and put some code, the expected result and what you are getting.

Comment: Sorry guys, here is the code from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup, I will make a few assumptions and take a stab in the dark. Have you tried nesting your charts in a `<div>` with a border?

**HTML**

`<div class="border-block">
     <!-- your chart here -->
</div>`

**CSS**

`.border-block {
   border: 3px solid #000;
   padding: 5px;
}`